# How to calculate this probability ? (uniform distribution )

Tags: probability

> We examine blood under a microscope for red blood cell deficiency,
>   using a small fixed volume that will contain on the average five red
>   cells for a normal person.
>
> **Question:** What is the probability that a specimen from a normal person will contain only two red cells or fewer (assume that cells are
>   ***independently*** and ***uniformly distributed*** throughout the volume)?

I think this is a question about uniform distribution, but I can't understand what happens in the context above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make some assumptions regarding the distribution.

Method I: (Poisson) If we treat this as a Poisson process with mean $5$ then the answer is $\boxed {.12465}$ by direct computation.

Method II: (Normal) Let's say that the total volume of blood is $1$ and that your sample has volume $V$ which is unknown.  Then, of course, uniform distribution tells us that the probability that a randomly chosen cell is in the given volume is also $V$.  We also assume that there are $N$ red blood cells in total (and that $N$ is very large).

We expect the number of red blood cells in our sample to be $VN$ and the standard deviation to be $\sigma = \sqrt {NV(1-V)}$.  The given data tells us that $NV=5$.  Since $V$ is very small compared to $1$ we approximate $(1-V)\approx 1$.  Thus we approximate $\sigma =\sqrt 5$.  We then approximate the distribution with the normal, so that the answer you seek is about $\boxed {.1318}$. Here we have used the continuity correction for the normal, so we integrate the relevant distribution from $-\infty$ to $2.5$.

Unsurprisingly, the answers are similar.

Comment: Why would we need to "make assumptions regarding the distribution" when the problem **says** it is the *uniform distribution*?  gong.y, If there are possible results of 1 to n, with the uniform distribution, the average value is n/2.  Here we are told that the mean is 5 so n= 10. The probability of any specific number of red blood cells, in particular 0, 1, or 2, is 1/10 so the probability of "only 2 red cells or fewer" is 3/10.

Comment: @user247327  Assumptions are needed because there is insufficient information.  We are told that $V$ is "small".  Well, what does that mean?  Maybe $V$ is the entire volume, in which case there must be exactly $5$ in each sample.  "uniform distribution" here clearly means that the red blood cells are uniformly distributed in the total volume.  Very different from what you wrote.

Comment: @lulu  If this is a Poisson process with mean 5 , I got $lambda$ is 0.2 and the probability is $ 1 - exp(-0.2 \times 2)$ (0.32968) where am I wrong??

Comment: @user247327 At first , I got your answer 0.3, and I am not sure...

Comment: For a Poisson process with mean $5$, the probability of getting $0$ is $0.006737947$, for $1$ it's $0.033689735$ and for $2$ it's $0.084224337$.

Comment: I don't understand the calculation you did.  For Poisson with mean $\lambda$ the probability of getting exactly $k$ is $\lambda^k\frac {e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$.  Here $\lambda=5$ and you want to sum the cases $k=0,1,2$.

Comment: @lulu Okay.  I see , Thank you !